# Convert Excel documents to wiki markup

Tags: excel, mediawiki, wiki, markup

Is it possible to convert [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) spreadsheets into [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) markup? I stumpled upon strange recommendations exporting to HTML and convert it into markup. Is there a solution, maybe exporting to XML first or directly converting it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know of three options:

1. Install a WYSIWYG editor extension like [FCKeditor](http://mediawiki.fckeditor.net/) (see also [Official](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_%28Official%29)). Advantage: fairly easy Paste As Word (and therefore also as Excel) button. Disadvantage: installation can be tricky.
2. Use a [macro in Excel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Helferlein/VBA-Macro_for_EXCEL_tableconversion). Advantage: a one-click creation of markup. Disadvantage: client-side solution (so need it for all users).

My preference is the FCKeditor option because once it is installed it works pretty well.

Comment: thx for the tip. i already tried the online converter and the macro. both failed so i'll try number two. cheers.

Comment: _macro in Excel_ page in wikipedia no longer exists

Comment: _FCKeditor_: Obsolete and unmaintained extension with major security issues which is also broken. The following other choices are available: 
[WikiEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor)
[WikEd](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikEd) but they don't allow to edit tables

Comment: Another online converter: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/mediawiki_tables

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in a graphical interface, with proper software.

- Install **LibreOffice** and add the "wiki publisher" extension, often contained in a package named libreoffice-wiki-publisher.
- Open your spreadsheet with LibreOffice Calc, copy your table.
- Open a new Writer document, paste with Edit > Paste special (RTF style).
- Find "Export" in the menu, select "MediaWiki (txt)" in the format dropdown and confirm.
- (Optional.) In your preferred text editor, remove any excess table HTML markup with a couple of simple text replacements and replace the first line `{|` with `{| class="wikitable"` to have pretty backgrounds and borders.

LibreOffice is free/open source software and is better than Excel at handling Excel's own spreadsheets, as you see. There used to be an [Office plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12298) too but I've not heard of anyone using it recently.

You may need [table styles](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/59255/paste-calc-table-to-writer-table-without-juggle/?answer=59262#post-id-59262), available in LibreOffice 5+; but in the meanwhile you can just [apply CSS classes to your MediaWiki table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#XHTML_attributes).

**Alternatively**, just copy and paste your table in a page powered by [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor), which is quite good for tables. If your wiki doens't have it, you could still use the [MediaWiki.org sandbox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Sandbox): paste your rich text, click the pencil button at the top and then "wikitext/source editing", cut the wikitext and paste into your wiki.

Comment: Wiki publisher plugin (as of version 1.2) doesn't allow to export from Calc, only from Writer. So you need to copy-paste the table from Calc to Writer and make sure it's copied as a table, not as an OLE object (see this for instructions: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21320). Then you can export the table from Writer as wiki markup. Also it will preserve some cell settings but not all of them; e.g. alignment settings are preserved, while color information is lost.

Comment: @Shnatsel yes you're right, I meant to correct my answer here after some recent conversions I did but I forgot where my answer was. Thanks for reminding me. As for the exporter itself, I did not recently export tables with colours but I remember that once worked. I've had more trouble getting any `rowspan` output (but my table was ugly; colspan worked) and I always get excess (HTML-style) cell styling that I remove with search and replace.

Comment: If the table contains links, VisualEditor deletes them.

Comment: https://wikimedia.github.io/VisualEditor/demos/ve/desktop-dist.html can be used to keep links in pasted tables. c.f. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T129546

Comment: @JohnVandenberg thanks! I've changed the suggestion accordingly.

Comment: VisualEditor doesn't convert to wiki markup. The pasted table is html. :(

Comment: @TheincredibleJan I'm not sure what you mean. The storage is always in wikitext. You can retrieve the wikitext either after saving (with action=edit or action=raw or the API) or before saving by pressing the "commute" button on the top right and switching to wikitext mode.

Comment: @Nemo I don't know what you mean with "storage". Maybe the "container". That doesn't help. The table markup wasn't transformed to wiki markup. It stays html. There is no "commute" button on 
https://wikimedia.github.io/VisualEditor/demos/ve/desktop-dist.html#!pages/empty.html
I expected markup like described here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Basic_table_markup
and not the resulting html like it is translated by the  MediaWiki software.

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore. I wrote the table by myself in markup... Next time I'll try Mr. Data Converter. It looks good. Seems to do it right. Don't know why I missed it last time...

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Storage as in the relevant database table. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table . The VE demo is indeed not my favourite solution, I've replaced it with the MW.org sandbox for now.

Answer (score 5):

My port of Shan Carter's Mr. Data Converter now supports the Wiki table format. You can copy & paste directly from Excel or from a CSV file.

http://thdoan.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Comment: Used and worked great. Also watched Network Activity in developer tools to confirm this is a client-side only app (no post-backs of potentially sensitive data). At least, at the time of writing this comment, it was. :) Nice design and tool! +1

Comment: By far the easiest solution to work with, takes 5 seconds to convert the table. Select as output "Markdown" if you are using it for the Gitlab wiki.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple [python script](https://gist.github.com/prschmid/e59c78dd5af480dfb7b7) that I threw together for my needs. This doesn't handle cell formatting or anything of that nature, but if you just need to get a large table into the MediaWiki format, it'll do the trick. It depends on [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Usage of this script is as simple as

```
python xl2wiki.py input.xls
```

If you want to save the output to another file, just do

```
python xl2wiki.py input.xls output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki supports HTML syntax for tables. The wikitext doesn't look nice and is harder to edit, but if you are just going to copy&paste anyway, it works. And there should be plenty of tools for converting from Excel (or CSV, ODS) to HTML.

Damn, I should find the time to add native CSV supprot to MediaWiki.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this macro](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Technik/Text/Basic/EXCEL-2003_Tabellenumwandlung_VBA) available on the main Wikipedia site.

It convert the Excel tables to wiki formating. The output is pretty close to the original excel file. it does transfer font formating and cell colors. There is limitation on the borders but they come from mediaWiki system.

You can find the Code at : 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Technik/Text/Basic/EXCEL-2003_Tabellenumwandlung_VBA

Comment: Even if the answer to the problem can be found at the end of these links, there is no guarantee that these links will still be working tomorrow, or that the content will be the same. Please copy relevant code into your answer so the answer is always visible in context.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2021 now.

You can copy basic Excel spreadsheets directly into MediaWiki's Visual Editor.

The only thing that's missing in the copy/paste method is cell formatting.